# character encoding in JSF 1.1

Tags: jsf, utf-8, character-encoding, sakai

I'm developing a tool using JSF 1.1 and I'm having this problem :
I have a String in my backing bean which is printed as:

```
./src.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./src.cpp:4: error: ‘dsdada’ was not declared in this scope
```

on a txt file.

But when I put it on a h:inputTextArea, it goes like this:

```
./src.cpp: In function â€˜int main()â€™:
./src.cpp:4: error: â€˜dsdadaâ€™ was not declared in this scope
```

-

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
and this
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
```

But it didn't work either.
can somebody tell me how to fix this. Thanks

```
/* String[0] as stdout, String[1] as stderr */
String[] results = sshBO.execCommand(cmd, timeout);

/* Done with SSH things */
sshBO.closeSession();

/* Bring the output and err to the presentation */
msg = results[1]+results[0];
FileServices.saveStringToFile("F:/myoutput.txt", msg);
msg = new String(msg.getBytes("UTF8"), "UTF8"); /* makes no difference */
```

on the JSP pages :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://sakaiproject.org/jsf/sakai" prefix="sakai" %>

<f:view >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
...

<h:inputTextarea disabled="true" value="#{SSH.msg}" styleClass="myTextArea" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character `‘` exist in Unicode of the bytes [0xE2 0x80 0x98](http://0xE2%200x80%200x98). When you use the [CP1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (Windows default) encoding to encode those bytes, you get `â€˜`.

You need to explicitly set the `pageEncoding` to UTF-8.

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

This way it will print the characters using UTF-8 **and** implicitly set the `Content-Type` header right.

Comment: Thank BalusC, I tried adding <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %> to my page but it doesn't seem to work. Same problem occurs. Is there anything else I should try? By the way you got a great blog. I did learn uploading file from your blog :).

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the source of your transcoding bug, inspect the data after each transcoding operation. Use a tool [like this one](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/java-character-inspector-application.html) to determine what the values should be.

For example, Java strings are being transcoded from UTF-16 (the encoding of Java strings) to UTF-8 by your JSP writer. The other transcoding operation looks like reading program output from the native system.

```
/* String[0] as stdout, String[1] as stderr */
String[] results = sshBO.execCommand(cmd, timeout);
```

For example, you can print the hex values of your strings using code like this:

```
for (char ch : msg.toCharArray())
  System.out.format("%04x ", (int) ch);
```

The code point `‘` should print as `2018`. Your file writing code may share a similar bug to the code that reads input, misleading you about the source of the problem.

---

```
msg = new String(msg.getBytes("UTF8"), "UTF8"); /* makes no difference */
```

This makes no difference because it takes UTF-16 data, transcodes it to UTF-8, then transcodes it back to UTF-16. But aside from that, if your string is corrupt, it's already too late. You're fixing the bug in the wrong place.